# Graphing separate scatter plots using MatPlotLib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe and trying to plot separate scatterplots for each Organization Group Code using MatPlotLib. I get the graph output combines and overlaps each other.

Here's my plotting code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

PubProtect = SCPlot[SCPlot['Organization Group Code'] == 1]
x1 = PubProtect['Total Salary']
y1 = PubProtect['Total Benefits']
area1 = 5
plt.scatter(x1, y1, area1, alpha=0.5)

PubWorks = SCPlot[SCPlot['Organization Group Code'] == 2]
x2 = PubWorks['Total Salary']
y2 = PubWorks['Total Benefits']
colors = PubWorks[['Total Salary']].count()
area2 = 5
plt.scatter(x2, y2, area2, alpha=0.5)
```

How do I separate both graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out Pandas plotting functionalities, for example [df.plot.scatter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html)

In this case you can group your DataFrame by Organization Group Code and make a scatter plot for each Code.

```
grouped = SCPlot.groupby('Organization Group Code')
grouped.plot.scatter('Total Salary', 'Total Benefits')
```

This will generate a seperate graph for each group code

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a figure and axis as:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
ax[0].scatter(x1, y1, area1, alpha=0.5)
ax[1].scatter(x2, y2, area2, alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and didn't want to bother with anything too fancy.

```
plt.scatter(x1, y1, area1, alpha=0.5)
plt.clf()
plt.scatter(x2, y2, area2, alpha=0.5)
```

That worked like a charm to me between the two plots.